# Round-trip escaping on all strings & XSRF protection for server-side communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

I am reading FAQ article of angularjs from https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

In the section of security holes in AngularJS I have find below statement

> *"AngularJS does round-trip escaping on all strings for you and even offers XSRF protection for server-side communication."*

But I am not able to grasp its meaning.
I have tried to google it but no proper description is available about this.

Can anyone explain above statement with example to get clear idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the round trip escaping part but you can read more about AngularJS's XSRF attack security from their website https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http... There it says:

XSRF is a technique by which an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data. Angular provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only JavaScript that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your domain. The header will not be set for cross-domain requests.

Hope it helps and gives me my first couple points :)